# Is there an "upsert" option in the mongodb insert command?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know this may be a silly question, but I read on an e-book that there is an `upsert` option in MongoDB insert. I couldn't find proper documentation about this. Can someone educate me about this?

Comment: Google "mongodb upsert", bang the 3rd result :) [docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Since `upsert` is defined as operation that "*creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria*" there is no place for `upserts`in `insert` command. It is an option for the `update` command. If you execute command like below it works as an `update`, [if there is a document matching `query`, or as an `insert` with document described by `update` as an argument](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option).

```
db.collection.update(query, update, {upsert: true})
```

MongoDB 3.2 adds [`replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/):

```
db.collection.replaceOne(query, replacement, {upsert: true})
```

which has similar behavior, but its `replacement` cannot contain update operators.

Comment: Apart from update, db.collection.save() also provides and upsert possibility.

Comment: It is translated to `this.update( { _id : obj._id } , obj , true )` if `typeof( obj._id ) != "undefined"` but it is nothing more than a wrapper.

Comment: @zero323 true instead of True :)

Comment: @AbdulHameed True. From the looks I am pretty sure it was copied from Python session :) Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Won't this update the document that exists(if it exists) with the new document?

Comment: What do you mean "its replacement cannot contain update operators"... a replacement is a document value, how could it *ever* contain operators?

Comment: In python it is `True` but in Mongo shell it is `true`. In Mongo there is no `bool` like `True`.

Comment: I recommend findOneAndReplace() instead, as it returns the _id

Answer (score 7):

As in the links provided by PKD, `db.collection.insert()` provides no upsert possibility. Instead, mongo insert inserts a new document into a collection. Upsert is only possible using `db.collection.update()` and `db.collection.save()`.

If you happen to pass a document to `db.collection.insert()` which is already in the collection and thus has an `_id` similar to an existing `_id`, it will throw a duplicate key exception.

Comment: Thanks. As the doc explains upsert is only supported for update and save

Answer (score 0):

For upserting a singe document using the java driver:

```
FindOneAndReplaceOptions replaceOptions = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions();
replaceOptions.upsert(true);
collection.findOneAndReplace(
        Filters.eq("key", "value"),
        document,
        replaceOptions
);
```

Although uniqueness should be ensured from `Filters.eq("key", "value")` otherwise there is a possibility of adding multiple documents. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-with-unique-indexes) for more