# How can I insert one document/row in mongodo using pymongo in django views.py file? using post method

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have connected one mongo db using below connections and I am trying to insert one record/row/document in that db using post method but I am so confused how to do that by below scenario.

> "By post method check if the record already present or not if not then
> create  a record"

This is how I made connection and connection successfully made. the fields in dcollection are id, firstname, lastname, student_id

I want to do this.

> "By post method check if the record already present or not if not then
> create  a record".

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
db_name = 'student_db'
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db_obj = client[db_name]
collection=db_obj['mongo_app_student']
```

Comment: do you ask to write a simple if-else statement for you? what's the question?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I am so confused to write that code inside post

Answer (score 1):

Mongo has an awesome set of upsert commands like `replace_one`, `replace_many`

see another great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974216/is-there-an-upsert-option-in-the-mongodb-insert-command) about it and, of course, -> [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)

see below example, hope this is what you're looking for

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.student_db
collection = db.mongo_app_student
collection.insert_one({"name":"vladimir"})
for document in collection.find(): 
    pprint(document)
```

Merge command

```
obj1 = {"name":"Vladimir"} # V in upper case here
collection.update_one( { "name" : obj1["name"] } , {"$set":obj1} , True ) # True means Upsert

obj2 = {"name":"Being Human"}
collection.update_one( { "name" : obj2["name"] } , {"$set":obj2} , True ) # True means Upsert
for document in collection.find(): 
    pprint(document)
```

another example from [pymongo docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html)

```
obj1 = {"name":"Vladimir"}
obj2 = {"name":"Being Human"}
requests = [ReplaceOne({"name" : obj1["name"]}, obj1, upsert=True),ReplaceOne({"name" : obj2["name"]}, obj2, upsert=True)]
result = collection.bulk_write(requests)
result.modified_count
```